# ajax - access to variables set in url:

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

form_page.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="js/process_truck_req.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/runonload.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="prform" id ="request_form">    
    <form name="truckreq" action="" method="post" class="truckreq_form">
        <label for="seltruck" id="seltruck_label"><font class="whitetext">Select Truck</font></label><br />
        <select name="seltruck" id="seltruck">
            <option value="Select a Truck"> Select a Truck</option>
            <option value="2011+Tacoma">2011 Tacoma</option>
            <option value="2008+Tundra">2008 Tundra</option>
            <option value="2000+Tacoma">2000 Tacoma</option>
        </select><br />
        <label class="error" for="seltruck" id="seltruck_error"><font class="redtext">This field is required.</font></label><br />
        <label class="error" for="seltruck" id="seltruck_noavail_error"><font class="redtext">Not Available on selected Dates.</font></label><br />
    </form>
```

process_request.js

```
$(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    $('input.text-input').css({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
    $('input.text-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFDDAA"});
});

$('input.radio-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFDDAA"});
});

$('input.text-input').blur(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
});

$(".button").click(function() {
    // validate and process form
    // first hide any error messages
    $('.error').hide();

    var seltruck = $("#seltruck").val();
    if (seltruck == "Select a Truck") {
        $("label#seltruck_error").show();
        $("#seltruck").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var truckSearch = 'seltruck=' + seltruck + '&outdate=' + outdate + '&indate=' + indate;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "do_truck_search.php",
            data: truckSearch,
            success: function() {
                var truck_status = $("#truck_status").val();
                if (truck_status == "nopass") {
                    $("label#seltruck_noavail_error").show();
                    $("#seltruck").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

runOnLoad(function() {
    $("input#projdesc").select().focus();
});
```

Take input form data from form_page.html, pass to process_request.js for validation. I only displayed seltruck, other form fields are set in form_page.html.

At the .js validation, the fields are check if they are filled out, if not, the error label class is displayed on the form_page.html.

The seltruck form field requires mysql to be queried and checked for availability. I have the do_truck_search.php script working great, but don't know how to pass the 'truck_status' variable from do_truck_search.php back to the .ajax call.

Once back at the .ajax call, I'd like a success: 'continue' or error: display the label#seltruck_noavail_error.

any help?

thanks!

**UPDATE** - can't get this to work? dataType: "text" in .ajax works though? any thoughts?

do_truck_search.php

```
if (($unixoutdate >= $dbunixoutdate) && ($unixoutdate <= $dbunixindate) && ($dbtruck == $seltruck_final)){
    $truck_status = "nopass";
    $data2 = array('truck_status' => $truck_status);
    echo json_encode($data2);
}
```

process_request.js:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "do_truck_search.php",
  data: truckString,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
      if (data.truck_status == "nopass"){
          $("label#seltruck_noavail_error").show();
      }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

I think the reason why the json datatype was unreliable is because a small square (probably a space) is echo'd from the PHP script. Using datatype: 'text' and an alert() in the .ajax success callback shows the small square, prior to the actual data text. My dirty solution was to use datatype: text, then just substr the actual data I want to retrieve.

I searched hi/low in the PHP script to find the cause of the echo'd space, but couldn't find it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do this:

1. In `$.ajax` set `dataType: "json"`
2. In the PHP script `echo json_encode(array("truck_status" => $truck_status));`. Note that no other output must be present (so disable your layouts, views etc.)
3. Change `success: function() {...}` to `success: function(data, status) {...}`; now the variable `data` will contain the key `truck_status` with whatever you set it to. So access it using `data.truck_status`.

Comment: thanks for the help! I was able to echo "nopass" in the PHP, and grab it using dataType: "text" in the .ajax call, but never did get the json method working, see above update....

Comment: i got the json method kind of working, seems like about 1/2 the time the data.truck_status is incorrect, or not displayed at all? I'm using alert(data.truck_status);

Comment: could the browser be cache'ing the data.truck_status? In the PHP i make sure to unset($truck_status['truck_status']); ?? thanks!